# How can i calculate first digit in $(13)^{139}$.

Tags: number-theory

How can i calculate first digit in  $(13)^{139}$.

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Let $a$ be the first Digit of $13^{139}$.

So $10^{b}a < 13^{139}<10^{b}(a+1)$, where $b= \lfloor \log_{10}(13^{139})\rfloor$

Now taking $\log_{10}$ on both side

$b+\log_{10}(a)<139\cdot \log_{10}(13)<b+\log_{10}(a+1)$

Now I did not understand how can i solve after that

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: "First digit" = from the left or from the right?

Comment: You can tell from the inequalities he wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Take your favourite calculator, and calculate $139 \log_{10}13$. Now let $x$ be the fractional part of this, and calculate $10^x$. Deduce the result.

Comment: Just entering $13^{139}$ in a calculator should work and get you 6.8885207452178e+154. Try https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=13%5E139.

Answer (score -1):

$13$ is congruent to $3  (\mod 10)$, so $13^4$ is congruent to $3^4$ or $81$ congruent to $1 (\mod 10)$, but $139$ is the product of 34 and 4 added to 3... So $13^{136}$ is congruent to $1 (\mod 10)$ so $13^{139}$ is congruent to $13^3$ or $7 (\mod 10)$ so the first digit is $7$.

Comment: The question is to find the first digit from the left-hand side (most significant digit).

Comment: The first digit is 6.